# How do i add the direction function to custom Google Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maps, direction

I followed this guys tutorial

http://stiern.com/tutorials/adding-custom-google-maps-to-your-website/

The tutorial is on adding a custom google map to a website.

Everything works fine, as you can see http://olivegrove.com.gr/?page_id=7

I just really would like to have the directions function on the map,
as it is done on the actual google maps.

Is there a way of adding this?

Does any one a good tutorial on the internet for it?

Answer (score 0):

It's not *exactly* the same, but it has powerful directions search capabilities; you may want to use the `DirectionsService`[<sup>dev-guide</sup>](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). If you are just starting out with Google Maps, you will also want to check out:

- [API-Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)
- [Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/)
- [Utility Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/wiki/Libraries)